# How to hide custom view with sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

We created some custom views and as far as i can see it's not possible to hide a view from certain groups users?

I know about view filters, but i really want hide the view completly from this group.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please look into this article .
Hope it would help. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-the-availability-of-views-for-a-location-in-the-site-hierarchy-HA010378684.aspx

Comment: SharePoint 2013 contains a "Disable view selector menu" option under the "Miscellaneous" section for the List View, if you edit the page and then the List View Web Part.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not simply use content approval within that document library to mark all 'Pending' documents as 'unapproved', and have an automated process or workflow approve any documents with a set start date?  This would hide Pending documents from standard users, while allowing any group marked as having 'approval' rights on that DL to see them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the data in your list views from a group of users (visitors) and show them to another group of users (admin). Edit the page of the view using Site settings option. Open the webpart which holds the list view in edit mode and under Appreances give Audience targeting . This will prevent the user from seeing the data if they dont belong to a particular group .

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint security model does not include any support for assigning permissions on list views. You could potentially hack the page with jQuery or something similar to hide the other views as options but this wouldn't be supported.

Users will be able to see all of the data for a list item anyway by going to View Properties. Do you have a security reason for doing this?

Comment: We have 3 categories of docs in a single library.  Pending, Current and Expired.  We mostly want to hide pending docs from this group.  It does not matter that they can see current or expired docs.  any good ideas to achive this with OOTB setup?

Comment: To add, Pending docs may already be approved but has not met the "Start Date" yet, so it must not be viewable to the group

Answer (score 0):

It could be done through SharePoint Designer, you can create the view and set a group to access this view

Answer (score 0):

You can use some third party permission tools to hide a view from certain groups users: BoostSolutions' [Column/View Permission](http://www.boostsolutions.com/columnpermission.html) or MetaVis' [Security Manager](http://www.metavistech.com/product/security-manager-sharepoint).

BTW, I work for BoostSolutions and I mentioned our product because it works for your issue :)